# Why compilation fails when I initialize one pointer string to another non pointer string?

Tags: c++, string, pointers

s is pointing to "this is a string" but when I initialize it to t,it throws error C2440 so my question is Why compilation fails when I initialize one pointer string to another non pointer string?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char t="5d";
    char *s = "this is a string";
    cout<<s;
    cout<<&s;
    *s=t;
    cout<<s;
    cout<<&s;
    return 0;
}
```

> error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char [3]' to
>   'char'

Comment: Note that after you fix the compilation error, you will get a runtime error (memory access violation) on `*s=t`.

Comment: `std::string s = "this is a string";`

Comment: @barakmanos: You do not need to write the same comment on the question and all of the answers. We get it.

Comment: @Ruchir Welcome to C++. Please use `std::string` instead of `char*`. [Bjarne Stroustrup says it well](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html): "If you don't want to use arrays and pointers, standard library strings and containers are (better) alternatives in many cases. If you use only low-level facilities, you are almost certainly wasting time and complicating maintenance without performance advantages"

Answer (score 2):

Because `"5d"` is a `const char [3]`, not a `char`.

```
char t = "5d"; // Incompatible types here...
```

Try this instead:

```
char * t = "5d";
// ... or ...
const char t[] = "5d";
```

Perhaps this example helps:

```
const char t[] = "5d";
const char * s = "this is a string";
s = t;
```

Comment: And the following problem will be a memory access violation during runtime at `*s=t`.

Comment: @barakmanos: sure, I'm just literally answering OP's question about the compilation error.